# Can I use noSQL document based to store json objects?

Tags: json, database, nosql

I am learning about noSQL, I read about document based database, and that noSQL is suited for developers, can I set the document format to be a json object?

For example, to store people profiles inform of json ojbects, and store the json as is in noSQL table? is this the right way to move on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general and in most of the NoSQL document database, use json (or if i want say it exactly BSON) to store objects. for example in CouchDB and MongoDB data store as BSON object. BSON is binary representation of JSON. when you work with this database you should save JSON and fetch JSON object. 
So in my opinion, you have answered yourself question, because document is JSON really.

I have created a presentation, you can check it for getting extra information
http://www.slideshare.net/HemanHosainpana/document-database

Comment: Wow! so, it will be much easier to store my schema as json objects, this means that I can manipulate the record easier as I am setting attributes to an object, right?

Comment: I strictly recommend read the NoSQL Distilled book (Martin Fowler). NoSQL databases have a lot of benefit and some drawback. It is suitable for some scenario. I think document database in general and MongoDB and CouchDB are so good for web development. please review the cited slide.

Answer (score 1):

Yep! usually it's the only way, for example MongoDB is working with json/bson as main document type.

But you should change a bit the concepts you will not use table in noSQL you will use the term Collection, and other specific terminology, Cause the main issue for programmers that are coming from sql to nosql they tend to organize the information in a relational way an that is absolutely incorrect and will produce bad performance issues in the long run.

Comment: Thank you, but, how to link a "collection" to another collection? in sql, we used joint table, foreign ids, but, I am totally new here! I think its easy, but I need a hand to get started :)

Comment: In noSQL terminology `JOINS` are replaced by references and embedded documents,

Usualy you will embed the tight related data. For example you have the class Person and the class Address, it's not much point into having a separate collection for the Addresses cause you rarely show them independently of Persons so you will embed them in Person Collection other case is when you have the class BlogPost in this case you will use Reference to the Person class.

Embed: you will place the whole document in the interior of the parent collection
` Person = {
}

Comment: hmm, I see, so we might end up with data duplicate if we weren't cautious enough ,,

Comment: In mongo data duplication is not an issue. Usualy the problem comes from schema. Sugest you to document yourself and use best practices.
http://info.mongodb.com/rs/mongodb/images/10gen-MongoDB_Operations_Best_Practices.pdf - good starting point